# aws lambdaを使用したサーバーレスな動的webサイトの作成

Tags: aws, go, aws-lambda

動的なサーバーレスなウェブサイトを作ってみたく試行錯誤しています。
https://qiita.com/kimihiro_n/items/15cce90ec93625c4445a
上記のようなサイトが理想です。
言語はgoでフレームはginかechoを使用しようと思っています。
apex でデプロイするのですが、あまりうまく行っていません。
goを使用した場合、僕がやろうとしていることは可能なのでしょうか？？

Comment: どのように「うまくいってない」のかも質問文に書いて頂けると、具体的なアドバイスが得られやすそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もちろんgoでlambda処理を記述すれば可能です。

残念ながらアップロードツールは知らないのですが、goの場合はコンパイルすると必要なものが一つになったモジュールが出来上がるので、それをzipにしてアップロードするだけですから、いちいちツールを使わなくてもcliを使えば簡単にデプロイできます。

例えば新規に作るなら、

aws lambda create-function

書き換えるなら、

aws lambda update-function-code

とかです。
シェルなどを書いておけば簡単です。